# Validation message is not shown

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Here is my js and html code for `gender` field:

```html
<input data-bind="value: gender, attr: {required: isMyClient}">
```

```javascript
self.Gender = ko.observable();
```

Here is the js and html file for first name field:

```html
<input name="entity" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value" data-bind="value:FirstName">
```

```javascript
self.FirstName = ko.observable().extend({
   required: {
       message: "fill in the blanks"
   }
})
```

Code for `gender` works fine as I am not able to submit without filling the field if MyClient is checked but there is not any validation message shown. I do not get the idea what is the reason behind that.

Comment: Where do you expect to see a validation message, and what do you expect it to say? Are you using the knockout validation plug-in? https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: @RoyJ yes below the field. Fields that I did make  required in JS files have error messages already saying "this field is required" but the ones whic are required when myClient is checked don't show any error messages but even it works perfect by means of I am not able to submit without filling them.

Comment: What generates the validation messages?

Comment: I'm assuming the ko plugin, as the question's tagged with [tag:knockout-validation]; but the the code in the question uses the html5 `required` attribute. OP, have you read the knockout-validation docs or getting started? If you have, please show us more (*syntactically valid*) code, i.e. a full but minimal repro of your scenario, and tell us what you've tried and researched so far, and be specific about the problem. As it stands your question is really unclear, and probably not helpful to others with similar problems.

Comment: @Jeroen  I updated the question

Comment: @RoyJ please see the updated question, the things is I don't get the idea when we use attribute 'required'  in html doesn't it make provided variable in js file required?

Comment: Why would you *expect* a validation message in the first example? You're not using the plugin at all, just setting the html5 `required` attribute with KO?

Comment: @Jeroen I  thought it links value with the declared variable in js file and    because that field is required it needs to show the error message which is provided by ko-validation.

Comment: IIRC you posted another question, can't quite find it anymore atm, but one of the answers suggested using the `required` attribute. IMO that was bad advice, because you seem to want to get full use out of ko-validation. In that case you should define *all* your validation rules inside your *ViewModels*, and not in your *View*.

Comment: @Jeroen I know it, but the problem is I don't know how can I use MyClient in another js file. Because I have Person.js file and Transaction.js respectively and MyClient is declared in Transaction.js. I don't know how can I get data about MyClient in Person.js file? I mean in html I am just using "$parent.MyClient" but it is not same with js.

Comment: Look, that's why I asked for a "*full but minimal repro*": how could we help you with that if we don't know what your code looks like. You should probably read through [mcve] and post another question with enough details / a runnable repro.

Comment: @Jeroen I am new to stackoverflow, I  just submitted new question and I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the html5 `required` attribute for `gender`, and ko-validation for the other. The first is in no real way linked to ko-validation, and I think you want to forego using it.

For reference:

- [html5 `required` attribute spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute)
- [ko-validation native rules (incl "required")](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules)

To get a message you should change your setup to use a ko-validation rule for `gender`, and get rid of the `attr` binding for the `required` attribute.